# calculating difference between dates in "12 Years" format

Tags: r, date-formatting

I have a data frame like below

```
Un_ID   Type    Child ID    Name    DOB Hire_date   Tenure
1   AMF 23  ASD,ghu 31-12-2016  14-01-1996  2004
2   GHK 45  dgu,khl 2/6/2010    25-05-1989  1993
3   FGT 65  hhm,mjh 11/10/2016  19-12-1990  1998
4   MHU 76  aaa,scg 11/7/2016   19-10-1993  1998
```

i am calculating difference between Hire date to today but i am getting answer in years (2004) and i want like 15 Years ,20 Years

trying like below

```
df$Tenure <- round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),df$Hire_date,units = 'weeks')/52.25),0)
```

also i want to mutate a new column in data frame as T/F in 1,0 to check if Check if hire_date is > of DOB + 20 but getting error

```
Error in df$DOB + 17 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

df$Hire_check <- df$Hire_date>df$DOB+17
```

Comment: The `DOB` and `Hire_date` seems to be not `Date` class.  You may need to cnvert i.e. `library(lubridate); df$DOB <- dmy(df$DOB)` and `df$Hire_date <- dmy(df$Hire_date)` or using `base R` `df$Hire_date <- as.Date(df$Hire_date, "%d-%m-%Y")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me. And you should be able to do something similar.

```
# Today is 2020-09-13
round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.Date("2004-08-13"), units = "weeks") ) / 52.25, 0)
[1] 16
```

However, your dates are messy. The `as.Date()` function assumes year first unless you feed it a format to translate, so it is subtracting 14 from 2020!

The functions from `lubridate` can clean up your dates before you do this and make it behave better. You can then use a similar approach with `difftime()` to determine your `hire_check`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(DOB = dmy(DOB),
         Hire_date = dmy(Hire_date),
         Tenure = round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), Hire_date, unit = "weeks") / 52.25), 0 ),
         Hire_check = round(as.numeric(difftime(Hire_date, DOB, unit = "weeks") / 52.25), 0 ) > 20)
   # A tibble: 4 x 8
  Un_ID Type  Child_ID Name    DOB        Hire_date  Tenure Hire_check
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <date>     <date>      <dbl> <lgl>     
1     1 AMF         23 ASD,ghu 2016-12-31 1996-01-14     25 FALSE     
2     2 GHK         45 dgu,khl 2010-06-02 1989-05-25     31 FALSE     
3     3 FGT         65 hhm,mjh 2016-10-11 1990-12-19     30 FALSE     
4     4 MHU         76 aaa,scg 2016-07-11 1993-10-19     27 FALSE
```

Here is the data in `df` based on the OP's sample data.

```
df <- structure(list(Un_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                     Type = c("AMF", "GHK", "FGT", "MHU"), 
                     Child_ID = c(23, 45, 65, 76), 
                     Name = c("ASD,ghu", "dgu,khl", "hhm,mjh", "aaa,scg"), 
                     DOB = c("31-12-2016", "2/6/2010", "11/10/2016", "11/7/2016"), 
                     Hire_date = c("14-01-1996", "25-05-1989", "19-12-1990", "19-10-1993")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hire_check for this check if i want 1 or 0 rather than true false....then...??